# change id name of carousel by dynamically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, carousel

I have using carousel in my AngularJS App. I want change id of carousel each iteration  but it is not working Please tell what did wrong?

```
<div ng-repeat="data in details">
        <div class="carousel" id="{{data._id}}" style=" width: 290px;
      max-width: 100% ;
      height: 250px;">

           <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="photo in data.photos">
                {{$index}}
               <a target="_blank" ui-sref="PhotoUpload">
                <img src="{{ photo }}" style=" width: 290px;
      max-width: 100% ;
      height: 250px;">
    </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" data-target="#{{data._id}}" ng-non-bindable data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" data-target="#{{data._id}}" ng-non-bindable  data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

First carousel image slide are working but after that second carousel images are not working if i click prev and next button first carousel images changing. but second images

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle dynamic id values like this:

```
[attr.id]="data._id"
```

and for `data-target`

```
[attr.data-target]="'#' + data._id"
```

Comment: Hi Zohab  i try change like this but not working **[attr.id]="{{data._id}}"** and **attr.data-target]="'#' + {{data._id}}"** as per my code

Comment: you are making mistake. Just copy and paste from my code. You are using curly brackets on right side again, so that might be the problem

Comment: curly brackets must in angularJS

Comment: if you use [ ] brackets on left side then you must not use curly brackets on right side.

Answer (score 0):

There must be possibilities your IDs are same for all elements. Please append {{$index}} within ID.

Try below snippet

```
id="{{data._id}}_{{$index}}"
```

Comment: Hi Ambuj i try above one with out {{$index}} becuz _id is unique  it throws erroe like  **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {{data._id}}**

Comment: the problems in data-target  property